# Split a pandas time-series DF into batches of 1hr/4hr/8hr etc

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, datetime, time-series

I have a pandas timeseries dataframe which has a value of a day recorded every 5 mins.

I want to split/groupby this df into every hour of 1hr/4hr or 12 hr etc.

For example :
My pandas df is as below,

```
| timestamp     | waterFlowRate |
|-------------- |-------------- |
|2021-09-07 00:00:00 |  37.012
|2021-09-07 00:05:00 |  42.768
|2021-09-07 00:10:00 |  31.795
|2021-09-07 00:15:00 |  28.745
|2021-09-07 00:20:00 |  37.766
|2021-09-07 00:25:00 |  37.780
|2021-09-07 00:30:00 |  54.340
|2021-09-07 00:35:00 |  37.739
|2021-09-07 00:40:00 |  17.345
|2021-09-07 00:45:00 |  21.782
|2021-09-07 00:50:00 |  37.738
|2021-09-07 00:55:00 |  56.811
|2021-09-07 01:00:00 |  37.783
|2021-09-07 01:05:00 |  47.776
|2021-09-07 01:10:00 |  51.123
|2021-09-07 01:15:00 |  22.764
|2021-09-07 01:20:00 |  23.750
|2021-09-07 01:25:00 |  45.843
|2021-09-07 01:30:00 |  36.667
|2021-09-07 01:35:00 |  37.847
|2021-09-07 01:40:00 |  11.779
|2021-09-07 01:45:00 |  37.790
|2021-09-07 01:50:00 |  37.731
|2021-09-07 01:55:00 |  41.345
|2021-09-07 02:00:00 |  63.504
|2021-09-07 02:05:00 |  66.068
|2021-09-07 02:10:00 |  37.826
|2021-09-07 02:15:00 |  37.787
|2021-09-07 02:20:00 |  37.686
|2021-09-07 02:25:00 |  37.853
|2021-09-07 02:30:00 |  41.761
|2021-09-07 02:35:00 |  37.787
|2021-09-07 02:40:00 |  24.740
|2021-09-07 02:45:00 |  13.791
|2021-09-07 02:50:00 |  37.755
|2021-09-07 02:55:00 |  37.767
|2021-09-07 03:00:00 |  37.735
|2021-09-07 03:05:00 |  37.804
|2021-09-07 03:10:00 |  39.710
|2021-09-07 03:15:00 |  41.778
|2021-09-07 03:20:00 |  54.785
|2021-09-07 03:25:00 |  37.773
|2021-09-07 03:30:00 |  47.794
|2021-09-07 03:35:00 |  37.751
|2021-09-07 03:40:00 |  17.741
|2021-09-07 03:45:00 |  23.868
|2021-09-07 03:50:00 |  37.691
|2021-09-07 03:55:00 |  37.798
```

I want to split this df into df of each hour.

```
"2021-09-07 00:00:00 to 2021-09-07 00:55:00"
"2021-09-07 01:00:00 to 2021-09-07 02:55:00" 
"2021-09-07 02:00:00 to 2021-09-07 03:55:00"
```

The goal is to find the minimum value in each hour and check if the pattern(n-th minute of an hour) is repeating. If yes then suggest the user to perform an action on that n-th minute of the next hours.

In the above case, the minimum value is repeating every 40th minute of an hour.

What I have tried is :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('./test_data.csv', delimiter='|')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['date_to_compare'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')
df.groupby('date_to_compare').agg({'Rate': 'min'})
```

The output is :

```
date_to_compare Rate
2021-11-25 00   17.345
2021-11-25 01   11.779
2021-11-25 02   13.791
2021-11-25 03   17.741
```

In the above output , I dont get the date of the minimum value , instead get the start of the hour.
My requirement is to get the Date Value of the minimum record.

I have also tried  `df.resample("1H")` , which again gives only the start of the hour time instead of the date : Time of the minimum value.

Once I get the Date Value of the minimum value , I need to check if this occurs at the same n<sup>th</sup> minute of an hour every hour.

The window timeframe can also extend to more larger time interval. Instead of 1 hour , the batch interval can be 4 hours , 8 hours etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the cleanest solution with pandas as i use a lambda aggregation, but here is what you can do. First, i create a random dataframe following your example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(freq='5T',start='2018-01-01',periods=(60/5)*24*10))
df['waterflow'] = np.random.rand(df.shape[0])

                     waterflow
2018-01-01 00:00:00   0.902711
2018-01-01 00:05:00   0.901397
2018-01-01 00:10:00   0.568458
2018-01-01 00:15:00   0.155888
2018-01-01 00:20:00   0.908864
                       ...
```

Then, given a frequency `f`, we find the minimum value as you already did with a groupby and minimum aggregation. For the minimum date, we apply the same reasoning but with a lambda function giving us the argmin of each group, and taking the index at this location :

```
f = '1H'
df_resample = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=f)).min()
df_resample['Date_min'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=f)).apply(lambda x : x.iloc[x['waterflow'].argmin()].name)

                     waterflow            Date_min
2018-01-01 00:00:00   0.155888 2018-01-01 00:15:00
2018-01-01 01:00:00   0.050121 2018-01-01 01:25:00
2018-01-01 02:00:00   0.001598 2018-01-01 02:30:00
2018-01-01 03:00:00   0.074867 2018-01-01 03:05:00
2018-01-01 04:00:00   0.007486 2018-01-01 04:55:00
                       ...                 ...
```

Note that if you have multiple minimum, this will only give you the first one in each group.